# BackgroundWorker in WPF executing multiple methods

Tags: c#, wpf

I've implemented a BackgroundWorker in my WPF app. My code is pretty ugly though. I've been told to write as little as redundant code as possible. IS there some generic Method I could employ to reduce the amount of code?

```
    //BackgroundWorker Databases
    private void worker_updateDatabases(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Databases = ModelSource.Databases;
        this.IsLoading = false;
    }

    private void worker_reportDatabaseProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsLoading = true; 
    }

    private void worker_FetchDatabases(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
        ModelSource.getDatabasesAsync(this._currentConfig);
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(ModelSource.Databases.Count);
    }

    //BackgroundWorker Tables
    private void worker_updateTables(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Tables = ModelSource.Tables;
        this.IsLoading = false;
    }

    private void worker_reportTableProgress(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsLoading = true;
    }

    private void worker_FetchTables(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        ModelSource.getTablesAsync(SelectedDatabase.Name);
        (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(ModelSource.Tables.Count);
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: [Have you considered `async` instead?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2011/10/10/from-backgroundworker-to-tpl-to-async.aspx)

Comment: Yep. Problem is, I'm a beginner to WPF, and only an advanced beginner to C#. Investing time into learning TPL is not an option due to time constraints (not due to laziness).